# Linux kernel memory barriers

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, memory-barriers

I am new to Linux kernel programming. I am confused by [the memory barriers](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/memory-barriers.txt) documentation, in the *GUARANTEES* chapter.

> Overlapping loads and stores within a particular CPU will appear to be ordered within that CPU.
>
> ```
> *X = c; d = *X;
> ```
>
> the CPU will **only** issue:
>
> ```
> STORE *X = c, d = LOAD *X
> ```

And then another example after that:

> It *must* be assumed that overlapping memory accesses may be merged or discarded.
>
> ```
> *A = X; Y = *A;
> ```
>
> we may get **either of:**
>
> ```
> STORE *A = X; Y = LOAD *A;
> STORE *A = Y = X;
> ```

They look like the same, what's the difference between the two examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, the documnetation is not correct. 
Actually your version of the file isn't up to date. There have been a commit in 3.8-rc3 which fixed the issue:
http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git;a=commitdiff;h=f191eec58803e1e16c3421638cdcc9195c425851

Hope that helps.
Matthias